# Displaying var = ... firstOrDefault as a string and not typename

Tags: c#, formatting, tostring

How do I format this var for displaying the date that is returned?

```
var lastDropStop = shipmentStatus.Stops.LastOrDefault(x => x.StopType.ToUpper() == "DROP");
debugFile.WriteLine("lastDropStop=" + lastDropStop.ToString());
```

Instead of a date, I'm seeing the type name:

```
lastDropStop=MyComp.Outbound.Business.Entities.Models.ShipmentStatusStop
```

Comment: Do you just need to access the date property on the type ShipmentStatusStop? `debugFile.WriteLine("lastDropStop=" + lastDropStop.WhateverIsTheDateProperty.ToString());` It hard to know without the object definitions.

Comment: The default behavior for ToString() is to print out the type name. While you can override it, usually that is unessesary. Just use the Propterty you want to have printed as was said by the other posters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing the object, you should write property name too like this

```
debugFile.WriteLine("lastDropStop=" + lastDropStop.StopType.ToString()); // or lastDropStop.LastDropStop.ToString() or whatever the property name is
```

Comment: Yes, totally thought I was getting a date, and not an entire object.